# Change Maven debug port number on runtime

Tags: java, maven

I would like to change the port number of `mvndebug` from the default 8000 to another one.

I know that I can change it via MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS environment variable like this:

```
MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000
```

But I would like to debug an aplication in two different windows paralelly.

The source code copyed to two different folder.

Any idea how to change the Maven debug port number in runtime?

Comment: Would you like to debug your own code or Maven?

Comment: I would like to debug my own code with IntelliJ used in remote debug mode.

Comment: Than you should do that within a Test case best or running inside your container whatever you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Please do not rely on MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS. This is not an environment-variable (!). MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS is a simple variable set by the script `mvnDebug` (`mvnDebug.cmd` on windows).

From the mvnDebug-Script-Comments you can find out what the true env-vars are:

```
# Environment Variable Prerequisites
#   (...)
#   MAVEN_DEBUG_ADDRESS (Optional) Set the debug address. Default value is 8000
```

Since the default-value for the debug-address is 8000 (what is a abbrev for localhost:8000) what clearly is a socket on localhost you could change this environment-variable.

> (..) application in two different windows paralelly (..)

This should be no problem. You have to change the value of the environment-variable MAVEN_DEBUG_ADDRESS only. This is because the 8000 is a abbrev for localhost:8000 and localhost is bound to the virtual ip of 127.0.0.1. Instead you have to use a full qualified socket address that contains the ip of the application-server (on windows you have a good chance that this ip address starts with 192.168....).

Try to use this command right before the execution of maven (replace 192.168.a.b with your appserver's ip):

```
set MAVEN_DEBUG_ADDRESS="192.168.a.b:8000"
```

Kind regards